# jquery - how can I select element after '.first()' using?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I select `html tag` after using jquery function called `.first()` ?

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body> 

       <div>
           <a>
              <img id="#hello">
           </a>
       </div>

       <div></div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

**JS (JQuery)**

```
var elemFirst = $(div).first();
var selectImg = elemFirst.$('img#hello');

// var selectImg = elemFirst.find('img'); <- It working but I want to select manual 

selectImg.addClass('some-css');
```

With Respect

Comment: why not `$('img:first').addClass('some-css');`?

Comment: What do you mean manually?

Comment: The example is a bit of a misnomer, if the element has an ID, that ID would be unique, and you should only do `$('#hello')`

Comment: @adeneo , If `Img tag` has not `ID` , should I use `find()`? 
thank you ver much

Comment: You can use any number of selectors, `$('div:first img')`, `$('div img')`, `$('div').first().find('img')` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('child','parent')` selector,

```
var elemFirst = $('div').first();
var selectImg = $('#hello',elemFirst);  //or just $('img',elemFirst);
```

Also, your id has a `#`, it should be just `id="hello"`.

If you need to keep this value in Id, use

```
var selectImg = $('img[id="#hello"]',elemFirst);
```

Comment: answer is really useful. Thank you bro.

Answer (score 1):

Use [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
elemFirst.find('img#hello');
```

This will search for direct and nested elements with the provided selector.

Alternatively, you can do

```
$('div:first #hello')
```

or even just

```
$('#hello')
```

since you are using an id which should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find()`:

```
var selectImg = elemFirst.find('img#hello');
```

But you have an `id` of the image, so, you just can do this:

```
$('img#hello')
```

Because `id` is unique.

Answer (score 0):

As in html the id be unique in html so striaghtly write

```
$("#\\#hello").addClass('some-css');
```

or

```
var selectImg = elemFirst.find('img[id="#hello"]');
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d46bo3gg/6/)